# How to give space between two rows In h:panelGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I am using `h:panelGrid` and i am able to give space between two component by adding

```
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
```

I want to know how to give space between two row ?

I am using `<h:panelGrid columns="12">` and i have 36 components inside `h:panelGrid` ,so `h:panelGrid` will automatically create three row. Now how to give space between these rows?

Comment: JSF is in the context of this specific question just a HTML/CSS code generator. JSF will be easier to understand if you learn some basic HTML/CSS beforehand. You can find good HTML/CSS beginner tutorials at http://htmldog.com. Once you're able to formulate the question in plain HTML/CSS perspective (e.g. `<table><tr><td>` etc), you'll get suited answers (or even duplicates) from CSS experts much sooner. Once having retrieved that, it's just a matter of rewriting JSF code in such way that it produces exactly the desired HTML/CSS output.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @BalusC I tried to add css like this   `<style>
 #contentform\templateForm panel-feature.table, td, tr {
     padding-top: 1em;
    
}
 </style>`  It is working but imapacting all panelGrid i want it for specific panelgrid which id  is `panel-feature`.what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: *"what i am doing wrong"* Skipping the CSS beginners tutorial.